# Is there a way to add a stylesheet or javascript file dynamically to a TYPO3 page which contains a plugin?

Tags: javascript, css, typo3, typoscript

Sometimes I need to add some js or css or both for a specific TYPO3 plugin. So far I included this via extension specific setup.txt like the following:

```
page.includeJSFooter.js = {$plugin.tx_fox_p1.settings.js}
page.includeCSS.css = {$plugin.tx_fox_p1.settings.css}
```

But if I add this static extension typoscript to the root template it will include the js and css on every page don't care if it is needed or not. Too avoid this I could create an extension template for every page where the plugin is placed, but when the plugin representing for example a sidebar tool and the site contains a lot of pages which uses this tool then this will be not so nice, to set an extension template for all this pages.

Maybe there is a way to add a plugin to a specific page and don't care about including css and js because it will include this dynamically and only on pages where the plugin is placed?

Maybe a typoscript condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller's action you can include header parts with at least two ways:

```php
public function yourAction() {
    // This will append each to the header
    $this->response->addAdditionalHeaderData('<script src="/foo/bar/one.js"></script>');
    $this->response->addAdditionalHeaderData('<script src="/foo/bar/two.js"></script>');

    // This will override headers with the same key, so make sure if it's absolutely unique
    // (usualy  some prefix + ext_key creates unique keys...
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->additionalHeaderData['absolutely_unique_key'] = '<script src="/foo/bar/unique.js"></script>';
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->additionalHeaderData['absolutely_unique_key'] = '<script src="/foo/bar/override.js"></script>';

    // your other code...

}
```

Comment: Ok, that's nice, but there is no way to add the files before the body tag end?

Comment: Ok this will work: $GLOBALS['TSFE']->getPageRenderer()->addJsFooterFile('/foo/bar/one.js');to add js files before the body end tag

Comment: @Fox, yes that's another option, anyway everytime I need to include some JS that should interact with my plugin's HTML markup I'm just placing it within the view at the end .i.e. using `f:uri.resource` VH ;). Of course your approach will be better if JS need to interact with other parts that are generated by other things - yet after your plugin work.

Answer (score 3):

I use this code for dynamic JS loading in Extbase controller:

```
class ShopController extends \Vendor\Shop\Controller\AbstractController {

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function initializeAction() {

        $ajax = ExtensionManagementUtility::siteRelPath($this->request->getControllerExtensionKey()).'Resources/Public/JavaScripts/Ajax.js';
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->getPageRenderer()->addJsFooterFile($ajax, 'text/javascript', FALSE, FALSE, '');

        parent::initializeAction();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you could wrap your Includes in a TypoScript condition:

```
[globalVar = TSFE:id = 10|12|15]
page.includeJSFooter.js = {$plugin.tx_fox_p1.settings.js}
page.includeCSS.css = {$plugin.tx_fox_p1.settings.css}
[END]
```

With the above TS your CSS and JS will only be included on pages 10, 12 and 15. There are more possibilities with TS conditions, as documented [here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Conditions/Reference/Index.html).

Comment: Yeah that's right. but currently there is no condition which matches if a plugin is placed on a specific site or am I wrong? For example you have a lot of pages like 200 hundred pages and not only 3 three pages where the plugin should be placed in. Then your condition will be not so great, because you have to add 200 page ids to this condition. But currently there is no condition like the following pseudocode: [globalVar = TSFE:page|plugin = tx_fox_p1]...[global] which would be nice.